# PhantomJS: TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating 'document.getElementById'())

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-scraping, phantomjs

One day ago I started messin' with phantomjs and their ability to read javascript generated data from the websites.**[web scraping]**

I'm trying to get element's text content by ID, but sometimes the particular website I try to crawl through doesn't have it, so then I get this error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('resInfo-0').textContent')
TRACE:
 -> undefined: 2
 -> : 5
```

Screenshot from the Command Prompt:

[image]

My code so far:

*1 step: reading the data from the file.*

```
var file = "path to text file";

var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.open(file, 'r');

var urls = new Array();
var index = 0;

console.log("READING A FILE...");
while(!stream.atEnd()) {
    var line = stream.readLine();
    urls[index] = line;
    index++;
}
console.log("FINISHED READING THE FILE");

index = 0;
```

*2 step: Reading the data from the websites.*

```
function web_page()
{
webPage = require('webpage');

page = webPage.create();

page.onError = function(msg, trace) 
{
  var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];

  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in 
      function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
    });
  }

  console.log(msgStack.join('\n') + " URL: " + urls[index]);
  phantom.exit(0);
};

phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) 
{       
  var msgStack = ['PHANTOM ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + 
   (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
    });
  }

  console.log(msgStack.join('\n')+ " URL: " + urls[index]);


  phantom.exit(0);
};


page.open('http://www.delfi.lt/paieska/?q='+urls[index], function(status) 
{       
  if (status !== 'success') 
  {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } 
  else 
  {                             
        var fs = require('fs');

        var path = 'output.txt';
        var content = page.content;

        var ua = page.evaluate(function() 
        {
            var x = document.getElementById('resInfo-0').textContent;

            return x;
        });

        if ( ua != null && ua != "" )
        {                   
            var indexas = ua.indexOf("(");

            ua = ua.substr(0,indexas);
            ua = ua.replace(/\D/g,'');

            fs.write(path,urls[index] + " - "+ ua + "\r\n", 'a+');
        }


  }

    });
    setTimeout(next,1000);
    }
console.log("STARTING TO CRAW WEBSITES...");
web_page();
function next()
{
    if ( index + 1 <= 288103 )
    {
        page.close();
        index++;
        web_page();
    }
    else if ( index + 1 > 288103 )
    {
         console.log("FINISHED CRAWLING PROCESS");
         phantom.exit(0);
    }   
}

        var ua = page.evaluate(function() 
    {
        var x = document.getElementById('resInfo-0').textContent;

        return x;
});
```

The error comes from here probably:

```
var ua = page.evaluate(function() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById('resInfo-0').textContent;

    return x;
});
```

What I've tried:

```
if ( document.getElementById('resInfo-0').textContent != null )

if ( document.getElementById('resInfo-0').textContent != "" )
```

So why can't it become null without triggering this error?

PhantomJS version is 2.1.1 binary windows package.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: I'm sorry if i forgot to add it , but at that time I was asking why I keep getting that error instead of the ua value becoming NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `document.getElementById('resInfo-0')` is null, but you're still trying to get `.textContent` of it, hence the error. Try

```
var elem = document.getElementById('resInfo-0');
if(elem !== null) {
    return elem.textContent;
}
return false;
```

Comment: It worked for couple of minutes, but still getting these errors.

Comment: Make an update to your question, add the current script version at the end, please.